# str_replace not replacing special chars

Tags: php, special-characters, str-replace

In a project of mine, I'm having a few upload forms. Since I live in Sweden, I want to encode the Swedish special characters to their respective HTML-code, so that encoding won't be an issue when displaying the data. Here's the code:

```
function format_text($text){
    $chars = ['å','ä','ö','Å','Ä','Ö'];
    $codes = ['&aring;','&auml;','&ouml;','&Aring','&Auml;','&Ouml;'];
    foreach($chars as $key => $value){
        $text = str_replace($value,$codes[$key],$text);
    }
    $text = str_replace("\r","\n",$text);
    $text = preg_replace("!\n\n+!", "\n", $text);
    $text = htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    $lines = explode("\n", $text);
    foreach ($lines as $key => $line){
        $lines[$key] = "<p>{$line}</p>";
    }
    $text = implode("\n", $lines);
    return $text;
}
```

Anyway, after running this function I always get an empty string from the `htmlspecialchars`, which I've understood is because of the Swedish special chars which is never replaced. So, my question is this: Why isn't the special chars replaced with it's respective HTML-code, and how can I fix it? I'm using PHP5.4.

Comment: Is the source code saved as UTF-8?

Comment: @Joni Yes, it is. `file -bi file.php` outputs `text/x-php; charset=utf-8`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you used `htmlentities` instead of `htmlspecialchars` you wouldn't need `str_replace`:

```
$text = htmlentities($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

If that doesn't work, check that the text is encoded in UTF-8 and not something else.

Comment: That doesn't work either, I still get an empty string in my return. So I suppose that the input encoding is the issue then?

Comment: I added `$text = utf8_encode($text);` at the very top of the function, and now it seems to work fine! Thank you!