# file_get_contents HTML + str_replace not replacing certain values (not apostrophe or special char issue!)

Tags: php, str-replace

I'm using a primitive way to replace certain strings in a prepared HTML email template (utf8). I'm debugging this for hours and am going insane already, so I'm posting a question here.

I checked these suggested questions/answers but none answer mine it seems:

- [question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17395212/str-replace-not-replacing-special-chars)
- [question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23987874/str-replace-not-replacing-apostrophes)
- [question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47373164/str-replace-not-replacing-string-with-special-character)

Relevant part of HTML to replace (read from file_get_contents):

```
<ol>
  <li><strong><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400; text-align: start;"><%q1%>: <em><%a1%>&nbsp;</em></span></span></strong></li>
  <li><strong><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400; text-align: start;"><%q2%>: <em><%a2%>&nbsp;</em></span></span></strong></li>
  <li><strong><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400; text-align: start;"><%q3%>: <em><%a3%>&nbsp;</em></span></span></strong></li>
  <li><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400; text-align: start;"><%q4%>: <strong><em><%a4%>&nbsp;</em></strong></span></span></li>
  <li><strong><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400; text-align: start;"><%q5%>: <em><%a5%>&nbsp;</em></span></span></strong></li>
  <li><strong><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400; text-align: start;"><%q6%>: <em><%a6%>&nbsp;</em></span></span></strong></li>
  <li><strong><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400; text-align: start;"><%q7%>: <em><%a7%>&nbsp;</em></span></span></strong></li>
  <li><strong><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400; text-align: start;"><%q8%>: <em><%a8%>&nbsp;</em></span></span></strong></li>
  <li><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400; text-align: start;"><%q9%>: <strong><em><%a9%>&nbsp;</em></strong></span></span></li>
  <li><strong><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400; text-align: start;"><%q10%>: <em><%a10%>&nbsp;</em></span></span></strong></li>
</ol>

        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>


        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <table class="module"
           role="module"
           data-type="divider"
           border="0"
           cellpadding="0"
           cellspacing="0"
           width="100%"
           style="table-layout: fixed;">
      <tr>
        <td style="padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;"
            role="module-content"
            height="100%"
            valign="top"
            bgcolor="">
          <table border="0"
                 cellpadding="0"
                 cellspacing="0"
                 align="center"
                 width="100%"
                 height="10px"
                 style="line-height:10px; font-size:10px;">
            <tr>
              <td
                style="padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px;"
                bgcolor="#d40a0a"></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <table class="module" role="module" data-type="text" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="table-layout: fixed;">
      <tr>
        <td style="padding:18px 0px 18px 0px;line-height:22px;text-align:inherit;"
            height="100%"
            valign="top"
            bgcolor="">

<div style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: rgb(77, 77, 79); font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 300; letter-spacing: 0.4px; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);"></span></div>

<div>
<ol style="font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400; font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: rgb(212, 10, 10);">
  <li style="font-size: 14px;"><strong><span style="font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><!--%location1%--></span></strong></li>
  <li style="font-size: 14px;"><strong><span style="font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><!--%location2%--></span></strong></li>
  <li style="font-size: 14px;"><strong><span style="font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><!--%location3%--></span></strong></li>
  <li style="font-size: 14px;"><strong><span style="font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><!--%location4%--></span></strong></li>
  <li style="font-size: 14px;"><span style="font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><!--%location5%--></span></li>
</ol>
```

One part is replacing as expected whereas the other is not and at some point it actually replaces some of the strings, but not all. I'm not sure what's happening anymore.

The relevant part of the code:

```
$html_content = '';
$mail_template_string = file_get_contents(get_template_directory_uri() . '/mail_template_questionnaire.html');
if($mail_template_string) {

    $myfile = fopen("DEBUG.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");

    // FIRST PART OF REPLACING this doesnt replace, even though DEBUG.txt says it should
    foreach($questions_answers as $indx => $qa) {
        $i = $indx+1; 

        $str_to_replace_q = '<%q'.$i.'%>';
        $str_to_replace_a = '<%a'.$i.'%>';

        $html_content = str_replace($str_to_replace_q, $qa['q'], $mail_template_string);

        fwrite($myfile, 'Replace '. $str_to_replace_q . ' with ' . $qa['q']."\n");
        fwrite($myfile, 'Replace '. $str_to_replace_a . ' with ' . $qa['a']."\n");

        $html_content = str_replace($str_to_replace_a, $qa['a'], $html_content);

    }

    // SECOND REPLACING PART: this works and replaces as expected
    foreach($locations as $indx => $loc) {
        $i = $indx+1; 
        $html_content = str_replace('<!--%location'.$i.'%-->', $loc['name'], $html_content);
    }
    fwrite($myfile, $qa['q']. ' -> '.$qa['a']."\n --- \n");
    fclose($myfile);

}
```

Why is the second part replacing and the first not? I changed the second part replace strings but they were <%text1%> before, so same as the first part and it still worked.

$locations and $questions_answers variables are arrays and data seems fine as it is printed in DEBUG.txt as I would expect.

I'm probably losing my mind here?

Any tips appreciated, hopefully it's just me.

Comment: What is “the first” and “second” part? Where is proper test input data to verify the problem?

Comment: Added comments to show the first and second part of replacement, also added a sample of relevant HTML that is received via file_get_contents.

Comment: And have you verified that `<` and `>` are actually those characters in the relevant places? Not perhaps HTML entities …?

Comment: The first part has `fwrite` calls, maybe they don't work correctly?

Comment: @CBroe i have, they are not entities. Also, the second part has them too and it replaces as expected :o

Comment: @Brainfeeder thanks, but unfortunately they work Ok. (would love if that would be the only issue).

Comment: `'<%q'.$i.'%>'` shouldn't be `'<!--%q'.$i.'%-->'` as the location placeholder has different syntax... ? (nvm saw in the HTML snippet that those are correct)

Comment: `$html_content = str_replace($str_to_replace_q, $qa['q'], $mail_template_string);` - in each loop iteration you overwrite `$html_content` here with what you just replaced **inside the original input data, `$mail_template_string`**. You need to initialize `$html_content` with the starting value _before_ your loop, and then keep replacing in what $html_content already contains at this point.

Comment: @CBroe nailed it for sure :)

Comment: Unfortunately, i do have it defined above, just didn't copy that part here. Updated.

Comment: You need to replace `$mail_template_string` with `$html_content` in the line I quoted - otherwise you are only ever replacing _in your original data_ at this point! And `$html_content = $mail_template_string;` is the proper initialization then.

Comment: Why a downvote please? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is to blame:

```
    $html_content = str_replace($str_to_replace_q, $qa['q'], $mail_template_string);
```

You have this inside your loop, but `$mail_template_string` is still the *original* value on each iteration.

You replace `X` with `A` in `XYZ` in the first loop iteration, that gives you `AYZ`.
Now you want to replace `Y` with `B` - but you need to do that on the *already modified* value `AYZ`. Your code currently doesn’t, but replaces `Y` with `B` in the original data `XYZ` again, so you get `XBZ` now, and it *looks* like the first replace didn’t happen ...

The initialization of $html_content needs to come before the loop, and then inside the loop you need to keep replacing inside the *current* content of $html_content.

```
// initialize variable with the original data before loop
$html_content = $mail_template_string;


// FIRST PART OF REPLACING this doesnt replace, even though DEBUG.txt says it should
foreach($questions_answers as $indx => $qa) {
    $i = $indx+1; 

    $str_to_replace_q = '<%q'.$i.'%>';
    $str_to_replace_a = '<%a'.$i.'%>';

    $html_content = str_replace($str_to_replace_q, $qa['q'], $html_content );

    fwrite($myfile, 'Replace '. $str_to_replace_q . ' with ' . $qa['q']."\n");
    fwrite($myfile, 'Replace '. $str_to_replace_a . ' with ' . $qa['a']."\n");

    $html_content = str_replace($str_to_replace_a, $qa['a'], $html_content);

}
```

Comment: Of course, I totally f* up, I'm too tired for thinking today it seems. A beginner's mistake right there. Thank you kind sir, was losing it already